# What do Democrats mean when they call a wall or barrier "immoral"?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, democratic-party, trump-wall

I don't want arguments for or against the wall/barrier on the United States' southern border. I would like to understand what Nancy Pelosi means when she or any other member of the Democratic party claim that a wall is immoral.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are some examples of statements by Democratic politicians and my best guess at interpretation:

Speaker of the House Nancy Pelosi called President Trump's planned border wall 'immoral'

> “A wall, in my view, is an immorality. It’s the least effective way to protect the border and the most costly. I can’t think of any reason why anyone would think it’s a good idea — unless this has something to do with something else.” 
>   [Source](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/pelosi-calls-trumps-wall-plan-an-immorality-2019-01-02)

What Speaker Pelosi seems to be saying here is that the border wall is immoral because it's costly but it's not even effective, and would therefore be immoral waste of taxpayer money.

Congresswoman [Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez stated that all Latinos](https://twitter.com/thehill/status/1093600535272251392/video/1) wherever they're from have the right to enter the United States, so in her view, not letting them enter could be perceived as a violation of their rights, which could be considered immoral.

> Rep. Adam Smith, the new chair of the House Armed Services Committee, who, echoing many other Democrats, claims that Trump’s campaign for a border wall is rooted in “xenophobia and racism.” 
>   [Source](http://thefederalist.com/2019/01/08/why-is-a-border-wall-immoral/)

So in Rep. Adam Smith's view, if the border wall is rooted in 'xenophobia and racism', then the border wall is immoral because xenophobia and racism are immoral.

Rep. Veronica Escobar, D-Texas, stated

> “I hope folks have realized walls are deadly,” she said. “When people are so desperate they will flee their country to go to another, a wall doesn’t stop them. It just pushes them out to more treacherous, dangerous, deadly crossings where migrants die in the desert or drown in rivers.”
>   [Source](https://abc6onyourside.com/news/connect-to-congress/is-a-border-wall-immoral-pelosi-says-yes-but-not-all-democrats-agree)

So, in Rep. Escobar's view, the wall would be immoral because it would make migrants' journeys more dangerous and expose them to potentially greater harm that if there weren't a wall.

Comment: @Shadur Talking about asylum seems to be a reference to the caravan. One of the mitigating problems is that the caravan crossed several *other* countries trying to get to the U.S. In other words, they didn't request asylum at the earliest opportunity. Does that affect the legality of their actions? It at least makes their motives suspect. Also, is the internationally accepted way to enter the country *legally* and then ask asylum, or does the internationally accepted way allow for illegal entry? What happens to those entering illegally who are denied asylum?

Comment: Pelosi’s quote is a great find, but I don’t think you quite unpacked her meaning. The key here is “unless this has something to do with something else.” This vague “something” strongly insinuates something immoral—my guess is racism towards South Americans and that piece of Trump’s rhetoric. With this in mind, Pelosi is saying here that the wall is “an immorality” not just because it is a waste of taxpayer money, but because it is a product of “something else” — something sinister, something immoral. This falls in line with Rep. Adam Smith’s comment.

Comment: @Daniel I see where you're coming from, but that would've required to speculate about what she meant by a rather vague comment.  I decided to stick with the reasons she mentioned directly.

Comment: Regarding the AOC quote: Instead of relying on some rather shady "news" sites to filter what she actually said through various ideological lenses I added the primary source: A video where she actually makes that statement.

Comment: I'm on board with Daniel for this one. She leaves unspoken what she feels the true "immorality" is, and that's her implication that the actual reason for the wall is based on xenophobic fear-mongering vs actual needs, and her belief that wasting national resources for that kind manipulation is immoral.

Comment: _Congresswoman Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez stated that all Latinos wherever they're from have the right to enter the United States_ She doesn’t say that in the linked clip, and as far as I can tell from Googling, she’s never said that.

Comment: @JustinLardinois My sources for AOC's quote were edited out and replaced. As per editor's source:  If Latinos are descendants of Natives and the U.S. is native land, and they cannot be 'told and criminalized', don't they have a right to come to their native land, the U.S.A.?  The wall would violate that right, and because of that it's immoral.  Her argument is straightforward.

Comment: @TheLeopard your source was a Breitbart article, which is hardly trustworthy. You're making a hypothetical argument based on her statements, and it's an argument she herself did not make.

Comment: @JustinLardinois I also used a source from Hip Latina.  Anyway, if you disagree, feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @TheLeopard it's not a matter of disagreement—the answer, as it stands, presents your inference as something she actually said. It's factually incorrect.

Comment: @TheLeopard, for one who would not "speculate" about what Pelosi meant, you are very eager to extrapolate AOC's words far beyond their context. A longer video of AOC's remarks is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=49&v=oEq3chXcsbU). Her statement that "human mobility [...] is a right" is in the context of ICE detaining people at times inhumanely. Even though this may sound like a support of open borders, [AOC explicitly said](https://bit.ly/2NoWcH7) she does **not** advocate for open borders. The quote you take is about humane treatment, not unfettered freedom to migrate.

Answer (score 14):

In terms of cultural references, it is worth mentioning a powerful image dating from the Cold War: the fence that separated Europe in two (and surrounded West Berlin) during the Cold War was called "[the Wall of Shame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_of_Shame)". Its numerous photographs were the symbol of the totalitarian oppression of the Soviet Union. It was also transcontinental, since it went uninterruptedly "[from Stettin in the Baltic to Trieste in the Adriatic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F61ikPeE7zM)", in the words of Winston Churchill (5 March 1946).

It had a strong impact on European mentalities, but on the US culture as well. US President Ronald Reagan famously stated "[Mr. Gorbachev, if you love peace... open this gate! (...) Mr. Gorbachev, tear down this wall!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCO9BYCGNeY)" (June 7, 1987).

Philosophically, there is a duality in walls, especially when they go from coast to coast: even though they are purportedly built to protect the people on this site from contamination ([the German Inner Wall was justified as an "anti-fascist protective rampart](http://www.inquiriesjournal.com/articles/232/berlin-after-the-wall-decades-after-its-fall-history-still-haunts)"), they are often meant the other way: "to keep the other people in"; in other words, to keep people as prisoners.

Furthemore, let us not forget that in US cities, actual walls or bureaucratic walls were built to segregate black populations from white ones, in the fear of an "invasion" of "people bringing drugs and crime" (Chicago's housing system left a strong memory of this; see also [N.Y. Times's book review](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/20/books/review/richard-rothstein-color-of-law-forgotten-history.html), 20 June 2017). That explains why the N.Y Times used the term **"[wall of shame](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/24/opinion/trump-wall-shutdown.html)"** (24 January 2019) about issues of racial discrimination:

> The wall of Donald Trump’s campaign and presidency has always operated
>   both as a discrete proposal — an actual structure to be built under
>   his leadership — and as a symbol with a clear meaning. Whether praised
>   by its supporters or condemned by its opponents, the wall is a
>   stand-in for the larger promise of broad racial (and religious)
>   exclusion and domination.
>   It’s no surprise, then, that some Americans use “Build the wall” as a
>   racist chant, much like the way they invoke the president’s name. And
>   it’s also why, despite the pain and distress of the extended
>   government shutdown, **Democrats are right to resist any deal with the
>   White House that includes funding for its construction**.

The term **wall of shame** has two connotations here: the first as a metaphor for **immorality**, the second as a [reference to the Berlin Wall](https://www.herodote.net/12_aout_1961-evenement-19610812.php?lang=en).

Hence, in the US, the question of the Mexican Border Wall does evoke two images, both of which are profoundly *immoral* in modern US culture: the Iron Curtain across Europe as tool of political oppression, and racial segregation in the planning of US cities (and these two images were already connected in the first place).

#### To moderator

This post uses abundant references. Please be more specific/helpful, to avoid your moderation being considered as overzealous.

Comment: Many highway projects are effectively walls that divide neighborhoods.

Comment: @emory - People didn't vote for a president so that they could build a highway, they voted to "protect the people on this site from contamination" (aka: racism) by means of a wall. Isolationism is immoral when you pick and choose, and don't hate everyone equally.

Comment: I don't know why others voted for Trump.  I voted for Clinton.  However, some highway projects have the same impure motives that you ascribe to Trump's wall.  Trump is not the first grifter on the scene.

Comment: There's a big philosophical difference between keeping people out and keeping people in. Nobody claims that the US wall will serve to limit the movement of US citizens.

Comment: Please note that the question explicitly asks for claims by members of the Democrats, not for personal opinions.

Comment: Although I agree that the Iron Curtain was evil, it was also effective. My father worked border patrol there for 2 years, and it was unheard of for anyone to cross that wall. Obviously a wall can have tremendous effects in putting people in choke points. That doesn't mean a wall has to keep everyone on their side, but it can be very effective in funneling people to a gate.

Comment: I don't think that this answer is poorly sourced.  However, I do think that it barely addresses the question.  It talks about some walls, and perhaps why those walls were immoral.  It hardly touches on the specific wall we're concerned with, or why Democrats of the modern era think this wall is immoral.  Overall, I think the content of this answer is only about 15-20% relevant to the question.  I think this particular wall does have specific political connotations that should be addressed more directly.

Comment: On StackExchange, relevance of content is measured by points. It is not up to you (if you are a moderator), to express opinions or censor upon what is relevant or not to a question. A moderator's job is to ensure that the answer fits formal requirements, using objective criteria.

Answer (score 3):

The [2016 Democratic platform](https://democrats.org/about/party-platform/#trafficking) says

> The world is experiencing a major refugee crisis with more than 60 million people displaced as a result of conflicts in the Middle East, Africa, and Eastern Europe. We support President Obama’s call for an international summit to address this crisis so that every country assumes its responsibility to meet this humanitarian challenge. While Donald Trump proposes banning Muslim refugees, we will look for ways to help innocent people who are fleeing persecution while ensuring rigorous screening and vetting.

They [also](https://democrats.org/issues/immigration-reform/) write

> Democrats know the importance of our country’s history as a nation of immigrants. We honor our fundamental values by treating all people who come to the United States with dignity and respect [...]

Democrats with some Republicans passed the [Refugee Relief Act](http://Refugee_Relief_Act) of 1953 in reaction to the end of WWII and the start of the Cold War.
They did agree with most civilized nations that people who faced **genuine political persecution** deserved political asylum, and that there should be individual hearings in a legal process.

Asylum should happen in the *first* safe harbor after leaving the place of persecution. There is no right for the refugee to *pick* their destination. The problem with that is that most wealthy nations, those most able to cope with refugees, have declared their immediate neighbours as "safe" and tried to prevent asylum claims by other ways -- migrants have to get in *illegally* to get a hearing if they will get *legal* refugee status.

So you can see Democrats supporting some restrictions on refugees, while generally being more welcoming than Republicans.

Comment: Note: Donald Trump, and perhaps some other ideologically-aligned conservatives, have claimed that Mexico is a country of rapists and criminals.  This is inflammatory.  However, by his own words, Trump is essentially saying that Mexico is NOT a safe harbor for refugees to settle.  This is a great reason why Trump and his associates can't make the argument that Mexico could have been a first safe harbor for refugees.  He can't make that argument without first walking back all of his previous attacks on the safety and crime factor of Mexico.